# Should I verify third party Facebook pixels on my domain with DNS TXT records?

Tags: facebook, site-verification, tracking-pixel

As part of some iOS 14 change, Facebook is now requiring some tracking pixels to have a verified domain (verified by adding a DNS TXT record).

On the site I am working on, Facebook pixels belonging to third parties are injected on different pages (based on if the page is showing that third party's product).

For these pixels to keep working, Facebook is requiring domain verification. It seems like there is no way around this: should I be concerned about verifying third party pixels for use on my domain?

I know roughly how DNS works and from that perspective, it seems safe enough for me to let Facebook know if a pixel should work on my domain (though I may be wrong). Are there any implications on the Facebook side of things?

Comment: Why help Facebook collect data?

Comment: @Steve I'm just trying to do my job.